# Removing Headers in eText in BI Publisher

Tags: csv, bi-publisher

We have a scenario where we should not display the header in the output in CSV using eText template.

Our output looks like this:

```
Header000001 Header000002
------------ ------------
Adetail1     Bdetail1
Adetail2     Bdetail2
Adetail3     Bdetail3
```

Desired output is:

```
Adetail1     Bdetail1
Adetail2     Bdetail2
Adetail3     Bdetail3
```

We tried all possible options in eText template like removing header section, verifying the data using BI Publisher Desktop tool, verifying logs etc.

We are not getting any error in BI Publisher Desktop tool.

Same question has been posted by somebody some time ago and it was resolved, but solution was not provided.

It would be very helpful if anybody can provide the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

The header will just be another block in your eText template. You can use the  `<DISPLAY CONDITION>` command to skip printing that block in the output. The display condition command specifies when the enclosed record or data field group should be displayed. The command parameter is a boolean expression. When it evaluates to true, the record or data field group is displayed. Otherwise the record or data field group is skipped. You can just give condition as false, and that block will be skipped.

Comment: We dont have any header section in the eText template.

Comment: We completely removed the Header section, but still it is showing up. We cleared cache, tried with another user account on another machine as well but it is still showing up.

Comment: Could you post your data xml and rtf template?

Comment: I did not find an option to upload the file, however I am adding the 1 record from the data xml here in the chat.

Comment: -<G_1>

<SOURCEBUDGETTYPE>OTHER</SOURCEBUDGETTYPE>

<SOURCEBUDGETNAME>SBF FY 2018 Ctl Bgt Detail</SOURCEBUDGETNAME>

<BUDGETENTRYNAME>SBF 2018 FY Control Budget 01</BUDGETENTRYNAME>

<LINENUMBER>1</LINENUMBER>

<AMOUNT>2</AMOUNT>

<CURRENCYCODE>USD</CURRENCYCODE>

<PERIODNAME>CTLBGT2018</PERIODNAME>

<UOMCODE> </UOMCODE>

<SEGMENT1> </SEGMENT1>

<SEGMENT2>URSTR</SEGMENT2>

<SEGMENT3> 120501</SEGMENT3>

</G_1>

Comment: @AnandV, zip up the data xml, and the etext template. Then upload it to transfer.sh, or google docs, or dropbox, and share that public link here. Ill take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a template using the provided data xml to output a CSV, without headers. A delimiter based template is used, but the header is not printed.

Access it from [here](https://transfer.sh/12s15j/BIP.zip).

Comment: I checked the template that was uploaded and it seems to be missing some key things. It generated output, but the processor had an error.
- <LEVEL> did not start at root.
- there was no row with <MAXIMUM LENGTH> <FORMAT> <DATA> <TAG> <COMMENTS>
- Maximum length for the separator was missing. (not sure how crucial that is)

After correcting for those, I was able to generate output that did not generate an error.

Comment: @EdHayes3, that was a sample for AnandV to refer. It definitely needs work.